# I still have ERC20 version EOS, how can I map it?

Tags: eosio.token

I am a EOS long time holder. I put my EOS in ImToken wallet.
The EOS I have is still ERC20 version, how can I change it?

Comment: Appreciation thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not register your tokens you could use this site to create an EOS account.

https://eosauthority.com/unregistered?network=eos